# Component installed yes/no list like in the VisualStudio Setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

I'm search a component/possibility that allows me to create such a nice looking "Component installed Yes/No" list like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [dotnet-forum.de](http://dotnet-forum.de/blogs/thorstenhans/image_60D45053.png))</sub>

What is the best way to do this?
A modified "CheckedListBox", a Table or paint it myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control rendered is a list view. You can add images and headers.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to use an ObjectListView.
It's easier to use than a ListView (and more fun) and it allows such things easily.

http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html